# How to properly use make with parallel builds?

Tags: build, parallel-processing, makefile, build-automation

I am having problems with parallel builds in make, namely having this definition

```
 rmlink:
         $(RM) $(ALIB)
         $(RM) $(BLIB)
         $(RM) $(CLIB)
         $(RM) $(DLIB)
         $(RM) $(ELIB)

 mklink:
         ln -sf $(ALIB_WITHPATH) $(ALIB)
         ln -sf $(BLIB_WITH_PATH) $(BLIB)
         ln -sf $(CLIB_WITH_PATH) $(CLIB)
         ln -sf $(DLIB_WITH_PATH) $(DLIB)
         ln -sf $(E_LIB) $(ELIB)
```

and launching build with `make` I will have those targets build

```
$ make
/bin/rm -f libA.so
/bin/rm -f libB.so
/bin/rm -f libC.so
/bin/rm -f libD.so
/bin/rm -f libE.so
ln -sf ../libA.so libA.so
ln -sf ../libB.so libB.so
ln -sf ../libC.so libC.so
ln -sf ../libD.so libD.so
ln -sf ../libE.so libE.so
```

But launching it with parallel build with `make -j 2` (or more) I would get :

```
$ make -j 2
/bin/rm -f libA.so
ln -sf ../libB.so libB.so
/bin/rm -f libB.so
/bin/rm -f libC.so
/bin/rm -f libD.so
ln -sf ../libD.so libD.so
/bin/rm -f libE.so
ln -sf ../libA.so libA.so
ln -sf ../libC.so libC.so
ln -sf ../libE.so libE.so
g++: libB.so: No such file or directory
```

Which in this particular case would remove my link to `libB.so` and won't create it again - breaking the build in effect.

How can I fix this to be able to launch parallel builds ?

**EDIT**

Adding something like this to `mklink` target seems to fix the issue:

```
mklink: rmlink
```

Please comment if this is the correct way.

Comment: You don't show the rules that have rmlink and mklink as prerequisites.  However, this makefile is fatally flawed from the standpoint of parallelism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When considering parallel builds, make decides the order in which to build things *solely* by the prerequisite lists.  If target FOO is not defined as a prerequisite of target BAR, then make will feel free to build both FOO and BAR at the same time.

Remember that having two targets listed as prerequisites to the same target, as in `TARGET : FOO BAR`, just means that both FOO and BAR must be built before TARGET.  It does *NOT* mean that FOO and BAR have any relationship to each *other*, at all.  So if you have:

```
foo: rmlink mklink
```

then make is free to run both rmlink and mklink at the same time.  If you want to have rmlink always completed before mklink is started, you have to declare a prequisite relationship between them, like:

```
mklink: rmlink
```

And of course, remember you must ensure that the mklink target is a prerequisite of any linker target that needs those links to exist.

There may well be more wrong here but given the parts of the makefile you've shown and the question you asked, that should fix it.

Comment: Just to be clear: the prerequisite relationship can be at a distance, it doesn't have to be immediate.  So for example if `A` depends on `B` which depends on `C` which depends on `D`, you don't have to explicitly list `D` as a prerequisite of `A`.  Make will understand the ordering required without that.

Comment: Ok, this seems to solve my issue but now I have something like: `make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.` since I use sub calls to `make` in my `makefile`.

Comment: That's a different problem.  You should mark this one answered and ask a different question, because in order to be sure about the answer we'll need to see the makefile rules that invoke the sub-make.  However, typically this happens because you are running `make` directly in the recipe that runs the sub-make.  You should never do that: you should _always_ use the `$(MAKE)` variable when running a sub-make.